# Images fail to load in Nextjs 14 once deployed to Production

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

In Nextjs 14, images fail to load in `production environment`. In `local environment`, the images load just fine.

- Images are stored under `public` folder
- Project builds Ok and is hosted on Vercel

I am using Nextjs [Image](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/images) component for automatic image optimization.

I did update the `next.config.js` file to

```
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "*",
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

and made sure that all Image components satisfied the requirements i.e. `alt`, `width`, and `height` attributes.

What could be the issue?

Comment: This might be a CORS issue in the prod environment. try to change the hostname "*" to the deployed hostname. for ex, `example.com`

Comment: Updated `next.config.js` file to specific hostname domain, still same outcome.

NB: DevTools Console is clear of any error

Comment: Alright, Could you paste only the Image component's src attribute code here? One more thing if images are not coming from remote storage then don't need to add this config in next.js.

Comment: <Image
        src={customer.image_url}
        className="rounded-full"
        alt={`${customer.name}'s profile picture`}
        width={28}
        height={28}
/>

Comment: looks good! so, the `image_url` property should be a string and hold a value like this, `/customers/image_name.jpg`.  For the given path image available to the public, navigate `hosted_domain_name.vercel.app/customers/image_name.jpg` should be visible.

Comment: Changed `middleware.ts` config from 

`matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.png).*)"],` 

to 

`matcher: ["/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)", { source: "/" }],`

It now works fine in PROD

Comment: It was blocked png images by the middleware. Awesome!